# Django - Modified Admin Form Returning an Object Instead of Text

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to customize an Admin form on a Django site so that one of the fields is changed from a text field to a select widget pre-populated by grabbing all the serial numbers from a table of locations (each has a unique number).

forms.py

```
class SglnModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.sgln + ":" + obj.name

class EndpointForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    sgln = SglnModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Location.objects.all(),
        to_field_name="sgln",
        label="Endpoint SGLN",
        required=True,
    )
    login = forms.CharField(label='Endpoint Login', max_length=32, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Endpoint Password', max_length=32, required=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import EndpointForm
from .models import Endpoints

class EndpointAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EndpointForm

admin.site.register(Endpoints, EndpointAdmin)
```

The form looks fine:
[Django Admin Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZfGW.png)

The HTML looks fine:
[HTML picture] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4eqG.png)

But the database is showing a "object(1)" as being inserted along with the rest of the fields.  This should be a serial number pulled form the select tag.
[Database row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju8RY.png)

Any hints as to why this is happening?

Update - just for clarity I added a simplified Location model (no need to have all the fields) and the Endpoint model but they are just standard models.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
        sgln = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        suite = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
        postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
class Endpoints(models.Model):
        sgln = models.CharField(max_length=19, unique=True)
        login = models.CharField('Endpoint Login ', max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
        password = models.CharField('Endpoint Password', max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
        tstamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for looking.  I want the sgln string data to appear in the Endpoint.sgln field not the entire object from the Locations table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious where the third image (the database one) is taken from, but the `Class object (id)` is the default format Django uses to represent Model instances.

If you want that changed, you can override the `__str__` method of your `Model` class.

As an example, this can be how your `Location` class looks like:

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    # Some fields including sgln and name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sgln + ":" + self.name
```

Now if you try to print an instance of `Location` model, it will print the result of `self.sgln + ":" + self.name` instead of `Location object (<id>)`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it caused all the <options> in the <select> tag to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a `ModelChoiceField` for selecting a value for a `CharField`. Once data is submitted to a `ModelChoiceField` the value is normalized to the model instance with the specified value, its meant to be used for foreign keys specified in a model not a `CharField`. For your usecase you should be using a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

```
def get_sgln_choices():
    return [
        (location["sgln"], location["sgln"] + ":" + location["name"])
        for location in Location.objects.values("sgln", "name")
    ]

class EndpointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sgln = ChoiceField(
        choices=get_sgln_choices
        label="Endpoint SGLN",
        required=True,
    )
```